# React 15.1.0, Pass entire state from parent to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I am using React **15.1.0**.

Suppose there is Parent "P" Component, and it contains a child component "C".

In older versions of react, when I wanted to pass the entire state to child, we used **{...this.state}** and then we used {this.props.something} from child component.

Is there a simple way in latest Latest React 15.1.0 for above Instance?

Note: I need to pass **entire** state and not individual props.

```
 <div>
    {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { title: this.state.title })}
 </div>
```

What I am expecting is something like below;

```
 <div>
    {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {...this.state})}
 </div>
```

In Parent component I have below code;

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return{
            status: 'disconnected',
            title: 'Hello World'
        }
    },
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Header title={this.state.title} />
                <div>
                    {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.state)}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

In Child Component I am experimenting using below code.

```
var Speaker = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Speaker: {this.state.title}</h1>
        );
    }
});
```

But in Chrome Browser, I get below result;

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question.. what's wrong with `{...this.state}` ?

Comment: It doesnt work in latest react version.

Comment: It works for me http://www.webpackbin.com/Nk_ES2MQW So.. in your example above (not using JSX) that's not a specific react syntax. you need the stage-2 rest/spread property babel preset

Comment: It has nothing to do with React, it's an ES6 feature.

Comment: @FezVrasta: It's not ES6. It's an experimental proposal for ES8.

Comment: Can't you just do `React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.state)`?

Comment: @FezVrasta to add to that, the usage of object spread actually inside a jsx component like `<Foo {...this.props } />` is in implemented specifically in jsx, so for that usage it is kinda specific to react.

Comment: @All.....thank you for your support. Bergi, I tried what you have asked me to do , but child component throws error for "props" being null. I am still unable to produce meaning output for transferring entire parent component state to child component.

Comment: I have added more code to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{...this.state}
```

equals

```
this.state
```

in this case.
Spread operator in ES6 (not React-specific feature) `...` expands one objects' properties into the parent object, see:

```
let sampleObject = {
  name: 'a_name'
};

console.log('Non-spread', sampleObject);  // Non-spread {name: "a_name"}
console.log('Spread', {... sampleObject});  // Spread {name: "a_name"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the below code snippet,

```
Speaker: {this.props.title}
```

in child component and voila!!! the code worked. Thank you all guys.

Below is the snapshot.
[image]